# Routing to ClusterIP via VPN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, kubernetes

I have the following IP range as ClusterIP from Kubernetes cluster.

```
$ gcloud beta container clusters describe CLUSTER_NAME | grep servicesIpv4Cidr
servicesIpv4Cidr: 10.86.240.0/20
```

I want to allow this IP range accessible from my DC via VPN.
After adding the "Remote peer IP address" to the next hop from my DC
[image]

**How should I create the route on GCE?**

According to the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/routes/create) of `gcloud compute routes create` command

> Exactly one of --next-hop-address, --next-hop-gateway,
>   --next-hop-vpn-tunnel, or --next-hop-instance must be provided with this command.

If I set one of the NODE to `--next-hop-instance`, what if this NODE is down?
How can I implement a route without single-point-of-failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664060/how-to-call-a-service-exposed-by-a-kubernetes-cluster-from-another-kubernetes-cl/31665248#31665248) there is not elegant solution at this point. I believe Kubernetes itself will take care of the nodes health in case of failure. Nevertheless,  you can still add multiple [routes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/routes) to different nodes.  The lowest route will take preference, but if the node ceases to exist the second route will take over.